# UIButton touch down action not called when touch down but called when touch moved

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Hi need to perform an action when user touched DOWN the UIButton

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(drag:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(drag:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

- (void)touchDown:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    //begin only called when I move my finger 
}


- (void)drag:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {
    //called when I move my finger, after touchDown was called
}
- (void)touchUp:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

The root view controller of my app is tabbarviewcontroller, and each tab is a navigation view controller. in the viewWillAppear method of the chatting scene I hide the tab bar.

the result is, on device, when i touch down, it's not called, and when I move my finger a bit, it is called.

Note:

1. using Long Press gesture recognizer does not work either.
2. If I put the button away from tab bar area, it works on device.
3. on simulator, everything is fine.

I created a sample project: 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_9_90avvmZtRmRDeHFkbFJLaFk&usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add your `touch` method?

Comment: @Avt updated. please note that the methods DID get called, my problem is the WHEN did they get called

Comment: I have just checked - everything works. Are you sure your button is not UIBarButtonItem? And parent view for your button is not UIScrollView, UITableView, UICollectionView?

Comment: Also try to disable all gesture recognizers before testing your button.

Comment: @Avt I attached a sample project

Comment: do you have problems running app on device or also on Simulator?

Comment: on simulator it's always fine. please test out my sample project

Comment: I've looked through the sample and tried a few things and not got it too work. Coming to the conclusion that you might have to write your own [gesture recogniser](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Comment: @Flexicoder same result for gesture recogniser (long press)

Comment: if it work on simulator, which device/iOS version has the problem? PS: does it have anything to do with the fact that the table behind has delays content touches enabled?

Comment: Quick question - Are you using an iPad mini? I've always had a hunch that the automatic touch-rejection Apple claims to use on these bezelless ipads might be causing issues with Touch Down and thats why they recommend TouchUpInside

Comment: @JackWu no I'm using iPhone 5s. please download the attached project and try out

Comment: @MihaiTimar no I'm using iPhone 5s, please download the attached project and test it out

Comment: sorry, I don't have a 5s available for test anytime soon :(

Comment: @MihaiTimar, You can modify the storyboard layout a bit to support 3.5inch

Comment: @OMGPOP Did this issue get resolved somehow? I'm having the exact same problem. I have a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem in a UIToolBar.

Comment: @Arash no, I even requested a tech support from apple with no luck

Answer (score 11):

Is this button anywhere inside a scrollview (including collection or tableview)?  If so, then that's exactly the expected behavior. The system waits to see if you're going to tap the button or drag the scrollview.  From Apple:

> Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the content. To make this determination, it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the scrolling itself. Subclasses can override the `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:`, `pagingEnabled,` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` methods (which are called by the scroll view) to affect how the scroll view handles scrolling gestures.

If you don't want this behavior, you can set `parentview.delaysContentTouches` to `NO` You may also need to set `canCancelContentTouches` to `NO`

Comment: not working. I have a sibling scroll view and their super view is UIView.

Comment: any other cases may lead to delayed touch?

Comment: And the superview UiView is the view for the viewController ( no further parents)?

Comment: Any luck on finding the answer?

Comment: no the superview is container view which is a UIView, the container view's super view is the controller's view.

Comment: Ok, I've done further research and can't find any other reason. And again just checking, you have no gesture recognizers on the screen?

Comment: no, but I have modified the controller's view a bit to allow touches outside screen frame. I updated my question

Comment: I attached a sample project

Comment: hi any progress? please try my sample project

Answer (score 10):

Hi @OMGPOP I have the same problem with you, Now I has resolved it add below code:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
```

I'm sure it's your savior, because I has download your sample code and add above code, It's work fine. like this:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;


[self.holdToRecordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.holdToRecordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(drag:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[self.holdToRecordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(drag:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[self.holdToRecordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.holdToRecordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any subviews on your button? These might be intercepting the touches and lead to the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: no i don't have a subview inside the button. i have a 'sibling' UITextView on top of it, and I hide the textview to show the button, so it's not affecting it.

Comment: I attached a simple project

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any UIGestureRecognizers on your button superview? They can cause such kind of delay.

Comment: no, the button's superview (UIView) is just used as a container, please try the sample project.

Comment: I've checked your sample project and everything works good for me. Check this out: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11819370/Krivoblotsky/push_button.mov

Comment: not that button. please try 4inch display and the buttom is at the bottom of the pushed controller

Comment: and don't try on simulator. please try on device. or adjust the storyboard if you don't have 4inch device

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue, and finally figured it out.

The issue here is that the button cannot receive action since its observer may be blacked out by the scroll view gesture recognisers.

What you need to do is to add a gesture on the container of the audio button, set gesture recogniser delegate to the view controller, and black out navigation controller popGestureRecognizer as below.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].isIOS7 && touch.view == btnAudioRecorder)//issue is iOS7 only{
     self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  }
 return YES;
}
```

And check it out, the button can now answer your touch down event like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it.

In my case, there are two adjoining buttons. (Left button is buttonA. Right button is buttonB.)
ButtonA is not called touch down event. But ButtonB is called touch down event.

I tried overriding `pointInside` in ButtonB class.

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    println(point)
}
```

Then, I tapped buttonA and called pointInside of ButtonB !!
point.x was negative value.

So I checked point and sendAction in ButtonB class.

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point) {
        return true
    }

    // hoge.left means hoge.frame.origin.x
    if point.x < 0, let buttonA = optionalButtonA {
        buttonA.bounds.origin.x -= (self.left - buttonA.left) //self.left is buttonB.left
        if CGRectContainsPoint(buttonA.bounds, point) {
            buttonA.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And tried all the answers post here, but none of them worked. 
Fortunately, my colleague had the same issue, and he solved it!

The solution is:

put following code in your relative ViewController:

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return .bottom
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?
        .interactivePopGestureRecognizer?
        .delaysTouchesBegan = false
}
```

The reason that touch down action was not called immediately is likely when your button is under the bottom of the screen, the touch down event will conflict with the iOS swipe up from bottom gesture. So it's delayed.